# How to pass data between three or more jframes in java

Tags: java, authentication

Does Anyone Know How to pass data between **three or more** jframes in java Because I want user to enter their details in login page then I will show them a page which have some **download** options according to there **account type** and then if they click on **another button** they will be able to see their account information like **Name, Mail** etc. Now I can access all the data from **MySQL** but for that I need minimum of a single value like **Mail ID**. So I want to ask that how can I ***transfer mail id from login page to download page and then user information page***.

I am Attaching Some Screen Shots Of My Pages Design.

**Main Login Page:**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA3ca.png

**Second Page(Download Page):**
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsUNE.png

**Third Page (Account Info Page):**
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B70rW.png

Comment: your 2nd and 3rd images are the same :P

Answer (score 0):

Define your string, say `input` like so:

```
public String input;
```

then in your text pane store the value entered as `input` and you will be able to access it throughout the project.